# Search After Usage API not returning logs

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, kibana, nest

**I am wanting to return the logs that contain "level": "error" from elasticsearch in a asp.net core web api application using NEST.** I looked into the search_after api [Search After API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/search-after-usage.html) and looked into another resource for [Paginate Search After](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after). On the Kibana CLI, I wrote the following:

```
GET elastic-search-app-log*/_search
{
  "size": 3000,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "level": "Error"
    }
  },
  "search_after": [3000],
  "sort":[
    {"@timestamp": "asc"}
  ]
}
```

I just set the size to something random along and for it just to search after each 3000 indice.

So on the .net side of it, I attempted to translate it as so:

`ESFieldsController`

```
        private readonly IElasticClient _elasticClient;

        public ESFieldsController(IElasticClient elasticClient)
        {
            _elasticClient = elasticClient;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ESFields> Get()
        {
            var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<ESFields>(s => s
                .Index("elastic-search-app-logs*")
                .Size(3000)
                .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Level == "error")))
                .SearchAfter(3000)
                .Sort(srt => srt
                      .Ascending(p => p.TimeStamp)));

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            
            return response?.Documents?.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

`ESFields`

```
namespace ESPractice.Models
{
    public class ESFields
    {
        public String Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the application and swagger comes up, I try to execute the get cmd to see if it works but it does not return the logs that contain `"level": "error"`. **Is there something I am doing incorrectly with the translation?**

[image]

[image]

---

**Additional info:**

`startup.cs`

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ESPractice", Version = "v1" });
            });

            // create a new node instance 
            var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            // settings instance for the node
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);

            services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(new ElasticClient(settings));
        }
```

***Everything below is from a separate application where I am writing the logs to elasticsearch:***

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                        .WriteTo.Console()
                        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
                            new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(context.Configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
                            {
                               IndexFormat = $"{context.Configuration["ApplicationName"]}-logs-{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
                               AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                            })
                        .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ApplicationName": "elastic-search-app",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Could you share index mapping?

Comment: @Rob Please see the "Additional Info" section on original post